# Custom tumblr theme - posts showing side by side

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a custom Tumblr theme (It's going well for the most part, but I've never done it before and I've hit a problem that I can't solve). As you probably know, posts are supposed to appear one on top of the other, so you can scroll down and see the next one. My problem is that they are displaying side by side (in a weird diagonal way). The posts aren't floated, so I don't know why they'd be acting that way.

I have the following code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{Title}</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{Favicon}">
        <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" href="{RSS}">
        {block:Description}
            <meta name="description" content="{MetaDescription}" />
        {/block:Description}
        <link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=La+Belle+Aurore' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poiret+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){

  document.getElementById('no-drag').ondragstart = function() { return false; };

  $('div#page').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).css('background', '#AE95BC');
  });
  $('div#page').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).css('background', '#372A52');
  });
      });
  </script>
        <style>
        body {
  margin:60px;
}
            .sidebar {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  width:230px;
}
.header-image {
   width:230px;
}

li img {
    max-width:400px;
}

.title {
  height:40px;
  width:230px;
  background:#372A52;
  color:#ffffff;
  font-family: 'La Belle Aurore', cursive;
  text-align:center;
  padding-top:14px;
}

#description {
  padding-top:11px;
  height:25px;
  width:230px;
  background:#372A52;
  color:#ffffff;
  font-family: 'Poiret One', cursive;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:10px;
  letter-spacing:2px;
}

#page {
  float:left;
  height:33px;
  width:33px;
  background:#372A52;
  color:#ffffff;
  font-family: 'Poiret One', cursive;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:11px;
  line-height: 33px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.s {
  float:left;
  color:transparent;
}

#pageturn {
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
  font-size:12px;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#372A52;
}

#pageturn:hover {
  color:#836097;
}

.next {
  position:relative;
  left:147px;
}

ol#posts {
  color:#372A52;
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
  font-size:12px;
  position:absolute;
  top:-17px;
  left:395px;
  letter-spacing:1px;
  line-height:23px;
  padding:25px;
  width:400px;
  background:#FFFFFF;
  margin:60px;
}

.post-background {
  background:#AE9DB8;
  opacity:0.2;
  position:fixed;
  top:0px;
  left:350px;
  height:100%;
  width:541px;
  z-index:-100;
}

.main {
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:-60px;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}

.theme-credit {
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
  font-size:10px;
  color:#372A52;
  opacity:0.6;
  position:fixed;
  right:35px;
  bottom:22px;
  z-index:-50;
}  

/*style this more*/div.caption {
    width:420px;
}
</style>
    </head>
    <body>

<div class="sidebar" id="no-drag">
<div class="title">
    {Title}
  </div><br/>
  {block:ShowAvatar}
  <img border="0" src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-TrC0-ZZuY7k/VTCOH9ZPELI/AAAAAAAAB44/5sG0F5-zETk/s1600/tumblr_n32n15ypTm1r907hpo2_500.gif" class="header-image"/><br/><br/>
  {/block:ShowAvatar}
    {block:Description}
    <div id="description">{Description}</div><br/><br/>
        {/block:Description}
        {block:ShowHeaderImage}
        <a href="http://cosplaysewingcrafts.tumblr.com/"><div id="page" title="index"/>1</div></a>
  <label class="s">1234</label>
      <a href="/ask"><div id="page" title="ask"/>2</div></a>
  <label class="s">1234</label>
    <a href="/tagged/reference"><div id="page" title="reference"/>3</div></a>
<label class="s">1234</label>
    <a href="http://cornflowershade.tumblr.com/"><div id="page" title="main blog"/>4</div></a>
        {/block:ShowHeaderImage}
        <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
            {block:PreviousPage}
            <a href="{PreviousPage}" id="pageturn">« BACK</a>
            {/block:PreviousPage}{block:NextPage}
            <label class="next"><a href="{NextPage}" id="pageturn">NEXT »</label></a>{/block:NextPage}

  </div>

        <div class="main">
        <div class="post-background">
  </div>{block:Posts}

        <ol id="posts">
        {block:Text}
                    <li class="post text" id="post">
                        {block:Title}
                            <h3><a href="{Permalink}">{Title}</a></h3>
                        {/block:Title}{Body}
                        <!--START NOTE SECTION (post info)-->
                        {block:RebloggedFrom}
                        reblogged from 
                        <a href="{ReblogParentURL}">{ReblogParentName}</a>,
                        {/block:RebloggedFrom} 
                        originally posted by 
                        <a href="{ReblogRootURL}">{ReblogRootName}</a>

                        {block:NotReblog}
                        {/block:NotReblog}

                        {block:Date}{TimeAgo}{/block:Date}
                        {block:NoteCount}
                        <a href="{SourceURL}">{NoteCountWithLabel}</a>
                        {/block:NoteCount}

                        {block:HasTags}
                        {block:Tags}
                        <a href="{TagURL}">{Tag}</a>.&nbsp;
                        {/block:Tags}
                        {/block:HasTags}

                        {block:PostNotes}
                        {PostNotes-16}
                        {/block:PostNotes}
                    </li>
                {/block:Text}{block:Photo}
                    <li class="post photo" id="post">
                        <img src="{PhotoURL-400}" alt="{PhotoAlt}"/>

                        {block:Caption}
                            <div class="caption">{Caption}</div>
                        {/block:Caption}
                        originally posted by <a href"{SourceURL}">{SourceTitle}</a>
                        {block:Date}{TimeAgo}{/block:Date}
                        {block:NoteCount}{NoteCountWithLabel}{/block:NoteCount}
                        {block:PostNotes}{PostNotes-16}{/block:PostNotes}
                        {block:HasTags}{block:Tags} {/block:Tags}<a href="{TagURL}">{Tag}</a>{/block:HasTags}

                        </li>
                {/block:Photo}{block:Panorama}
                    <li class="post panorama" id="post">
                        {LinkOpenTag}
                            <img src="{PhotoURL-Panorama}" alt="{PhotoAlt}"/>
                        {LinkCloseTag}{block:Caption}
                            <div class="caption">{Caption}</div>
                        {/block:Caption}
                        originally posted by <a href"{SourceURL}">{SourceTitle}</a>
                        {block:Date}{TimeAgo}{/block:Date}
                        {block:NoteCount}{NoteCountWithLabel}{/block:NoteCount}
                        {block:PostNotes}{PostNotes-16}{/block:PostNotes}
                        {block:HasTags}{block:Tags} {/block:Tags}<a href="{TagURL}">{Tag}</a>{/block:HasTags}
                    </li>
                {/block:Panorama}{block:Photoset}
                    <li class="post photoset" id="post">
                        {Photoset-400}{block:Caption}
                            <div class="caption">{Caption}</div>
                        {/block:Caption}
                        originally posted by <a href"{SourceURL}">{SourceTitle}</a>
                        {block:Date}{TimeAgo}{/block:Date}
                        {block:NoteCount}{NoteCountWithLabel}{/block:NoteCount}
                        {block:PostNotes}{PostNotes-16}{/block:PostNotes}
                        {block:HasTags}{block:Tags} {/block:Tags}<a href="{TagURL}">{Tag}</a>{/block:HasTags}
                    </li>
                {/block:Photoset}{block:Quote}
                    <li class="post quote" id="post">
                        "{Quote}"

                        {block:Source}
                            <div class="source">{Source}</div>
                        {/block:Source}
                        originally posted by <a href"{SourceURL}">{SourceTitle}</a>
                        {block:Date}{TimeAgo}{/block:Date}
                        {block:NoteCount}{NoteCountWithLabel}{/block:NoteCount}
                        {block:PostNotes}{PostNotes-16}{/block:PostNotes}
                        {block:HasTags}{block:Tags} {/block:Tags}<a href="{TagURL}">{Tag}</a>{/block:HasTags}
                    </li>
                {/block:Quote}{block:Link}
                    <li class="post link" id="post">
                        <a href="{URL}" class="link" {Target}>{Name}</a>

                        {block:Description}
                            <div class="description">{Description}</div>
                        {/block:Description}
                        originally posted by <a href"{SourceURL}">{SourceTitle}</a>
                        {block:Date}{TimeAgo}{/block:Date}
                        {block:NoteCount}{NoteCountWithLabel}{/block:NoteCount}
                        {block:PostNotes}{PostNotes-16}{/block:PostNotes}
                        {block:HasTags}{block:Tags} {/block:Tags}<a href="{TagURL}">{Tag}</a>{/block:HasTags}
                    </li>
                {/block:Link}{block:Chat}
                    <li class="post chat" id="post">
                        {block:Title}
                            <h3><a href="{Permalink}">{Title}</a></h3>
                        {/block:Title}

                        <ul class="chat" id="post">
                            {block:Lines}
                                <li class="{Alt} user_{UserNumber}">
                                    {block:Label}
                                        <span class="label">{Label}</span>
                                    {/block:Label}{Line}
                                </li>
                            {/block:Lines}
                        </ul>
                        originally posted by <a href"{SourceURL}">{SourceTitle}</a>
                        {block:Date}{TimeAgo}{/block:Date}
                        {block:NoteCount}{NoteCountWithLabel}{/block:NoteCount}
                        {block:PostNotes}{PostNotes-16}{/block:PostNotes}
                        {block:HasTags}{block:Tags} {/block:Tags}<a href="{TagURL}">{Tag}</a>{/block:HasTags}
                    </li>
                {/block:Chat}{block:Video}
                    <li class="post video" id="post">
                        {Video-400}{block:Caption}
                            <div class="caption">{Caption}</div>
                        {/block:Caption}
                        {block:Date}{TimeAgo}{/block:Date}
                        {block:NoteCount}{NoteCountWithLabel}{/block:NoteCount}
                        {block:PostNotes}{PostNotes-16}{/block:PostNotes}
                    </li>
                {/block:Video}{block:Audio}
                    <li class="post audio" id="post">
                        {AudioEmbed}{block:Caption}
                            <div class="caption">{Caption}</div>
                        {/block:Caption}
                        {block:Date}{TimeAgo}{/block:Date}
                        {block:NoteCount}{NoteCountWithLabel}{/block:NoteCount}
                        {block:PostNotes}{PostNotes-16}{/block:PostNotes}
                    </li>
                {/block:Audio}{/block:Posts}
        </ol></div>

        <div class="theme-credit">
  theme by me
</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

(Please ignore the fact that all the notes/reblog info are different on different post types. I decided to work on that stuff on text posts only, after which I'll copy it and make the same adjustments to photosets and videos, etc.)

Anyhow, help would be greatly appreciated. Side-by-side posts are really not something I can keep.

P.s. Incase you need to see a visual, the blog url is http://cosplaysewingcrafts.tumblr.com/, and my basic outline for how it's *supposed* to look is at http://jsbin.com/bopogi/3. (next and back buttons should show when more than 1 page exists on the blog, so don't worry about that.)

Comment: Diagonal usually means an unclosed/extra box somewhere. Can you post the entire HTML?

Comment: @VincentLee Alright, all the HTML is shown now.